# Funny result in New and Nothing

Tags: vb6

I'm using VB6, and just found something funny in my team member's code.

```
Dim anObject As New AClass
Set anObject = Nothing

anObject.DoingSomeThing
```

What I expect, the code should fail since anObject is set to Nothing now, but the code can work without error?

If I change the above codes to

```
Dim anObject As AClass
Set anObject = New AClass
Set anObject = Nothing

anObject.DoingSomeThing
```

This will fail since anObject is Nothing now.

I cannot understand why the code can work at 1st code but fail in 2nd code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VB6, if you declare some object `As New`, then VB internally places hidden code to check object presence and optionally instantiate object before **every** use of that object. Explictly such code would look as:

```
If anObject Is Nothing Then Set anObject = New AClass
```

In second case you have to maintain object presence yourself.

Note - better do not use As New. Its performance is worse and if you ever need to port your project to VB.NET, then behavior changes; in VB.NET declaring variable `As New` just initializes it at first, but doesn't re-initailize it after setting it to `Nothing`.